# Why/how does the virtual-ness of a base class change the behaviour of the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I dont understand the behaviour of this snippet: (compiled with clang++ 3.0)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual void bar() {}

    bool foo = false;
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    Derived() { Base::foo = true; }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    Base b(d);

    cout << b.foo << endl; // prints 0
                           // prints 1 if "virtual void bar() {}" is removed

}
```

Why does the function Base::bar() have any effect on the copying of Base::foo ?

Comment: @Benno I can't reproduce that (though I only have versions of clang that are more recent than 3.0)

Comment: I tested in my Ubuntu Qt Creator, It prints 1 always.

Comment: Wait, how is `foo` being intialized inside `Base` like that? As far as I'm aware, you can only do that with `static`, `const`, integral types. Is this a new feature of C++11?

Comment: Tested in G++ 4.8, it always print 1.

Comment: In Qt there's warning for foo = true but not an error by default settings.

Comment: @Benno: Did you have the c++11 flag on?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: I don't get any warning or error, even with `-Wall -Wpedantic`...

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker: My warning message:  warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]

Comment: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11418 edit: please note the attachment linked to the first post for the bug report

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: Of course... This code is definitely C++11, you have to enable the flag!

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, I do. Though when I remove the flag it will give me "warning: in-class initialization of non-static data member accepted as a C++11 extension", but the program output is exactly the same.

Comment: I think what's happening is that Derived has a Base object at it's base address, foo is inside the Base object.  In Derived, foo is true.  When you copy construct a Base using Derived, it will use Derived's Base structure for the copy, which has the `foo=true`

Comment: @user2485710: I believe you nailed it (since `virtual` affects the POD-ness), I also believe it would be worth an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem looks similar to the one [reported as a bug here](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11418) in the official bugzilla for the llvm project.

As you can see is a recognized bug and it's been patched in the newer versions of Clang, you should switch to newer version of the frontend to fix this issue; in the bug report is also specified the exact revision of clang that is offering a patch for this issue.